# Is this SQL running slowly because of the code? Or the external db calls?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

So, this is a pretty simple thing, I should think. It runs without error, but takes forever (about 1.5 hours when limited to 'top 1000' records, and over 5 hours without that limit).

I am relatively new to writing SQL and more accustomed to using GUIs to get my reporting done, but this is needed to make data available for another project so it needs to be setup as an SSIS package to keep stuff up to date.

The intent here is to pull data from the TTS db and park it in the table which is on another db. TTS is an Oracle db and the working db is MSSQL. I'm running this in MS SQL Server Manager 2008.

My suspicion is that it's dragging because either the MS-to-Oracle thing isn't happy, or because I've built the logic in the Where clause instead of doing table joins in the From clause.

Thoughts?

```
Insert into 
OCC.Workflow_Step (INV_SEQ_ID, DATE_ENTERED, DATE_EXITED, [DESCRIPTION])

Select
INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID,
Cast(WS.DATE_ENTERED as date) DATE_ENTERED,
Cast(WS.DATE_EXITED as date) DATE_EXITED,
WFS.[DESCRIPTION]

From
TTS..BT51.INVOICE INV,
TTS..BT51.WRK WRK,
TTS..BT51.WRK_STATE WS,
TTS..BT51.WF_STATE WFS

Where
INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID=WRK.FK_ID
and WRK.WRK_ID=WS.WRK_ID
and WS.WF_STATE_ID=WFS.WF_STATE_ID
and WS.DATE_EXITED is null
;
```

Thank you for your time and effort. I'm fairly sure this is something I should know but being new, there are some nuances that I don't know whether they are systematic, or just me being me. :/

Updated/troubleshooting code as requested below:

```
Select count (*)
--INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID,
--cast(WS.DATE_ENTERED as date) DATE_ENTERED,
--cast(WS.DATE_EXITED as date) DATE_EXITED,
--WFS.[DESCRIPTION]

From
TTS..BT51.INVOICE as INV
Inner join TTS..BT51.WRK as WRK on INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID=WRK.FK_ID
inner join TTS..BT51.WRK_STATE as WS on WRK.WRK_ID=WS.WRK_ID
inner join TTS..BT51.WF_STATE as WFS on WS.WF_STATE_ID=WFS.WF_STATE_ID

Where
WS.DATE_EXITED is null
;
```

Okay, I sat down with a guy who knows the Oracle side of this equation better and we came up with the below. Runtime went from over 7 hours to under ten minutes.

```
select asdf.*
from

openquery([TTS], '

Select
INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID,
WS.DATE_ENTERED,
WS.DATE_EXITED,
WFS.DESCRIPTION

From

BT51.INVOICE INV
inner join BT51.WRK on INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID=WRK.FK_ID
inner join BT51.WRK_STATE WS on WRK.WRK_ID=WS.WRK_ID and WS.DATE_EXITED is null
inner join BT51.WF_STATE WFS on WS.WF_STATE_ID=WFS.WF_STATE_ID


') asdf

inner join occ.amo_occ_stg stg on stg.invoice_seq_id=asdf.INVOICE_SEQ_ID
```

Thank you all for your time and energy on this. It is immensely appreciated. :)

Comment: So... how many records in each of those tables? And also, remember - if you have any indexes on `OCC.Workflow_Step` remove them during insert and then re-apply

Comment: Query completed in just over 7 hours. It inserted just over 6.6 million rows. There are no indexed fields in the target table. :(

Comment: könnt ihr mich hören? how many records in each of the tables in your join?

Comment: Apologies. Looks like the largest record set, in the INV table, is about 7.7m records. The rest are some fraction of that one as they are all reference/lookup tables.

Comment: I mean, come on - you are inserting data here. Run your select using `select count(*)` and see how much time that will take. Place your smallest table in From first and use `inner join-on`. I think, modern sql server knows how to optimize it independently of what you write but you can use Sql profiler and see number of reeds, etc in both approaches. But do separate your query from your insert and see how long it takes to just enumerate your records

Comment: check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Okay, so I figured out how to do the logic with actual joins rather than filters under the where clause. Running it with that change (only the is null under where now) and as a select query without the insert, it's still taking seven hours to complete. :( Thank you for you time, by the way, I really appreciate it. Sorry I'm such a n00b. :/

Comment: My friend, you need to understand. What you did is good for formatting query, it is like following sql standards. But sql server optimizer would build exactly same execution plan, if it is `inner join` vs `where t1.f1 = t2.f2`. May be some minor improvement if you list smallest tables first. **The main**  thing for you was to run `select count(*) [From TTS.BT51 .....where WS.DATE_EXITED is null ]`. See how long it takes to get that result. And post your updated query instead of old one in your question

Comment: Okay, I ran the count (code above hopefully), and it took 7:36:55 to complete.

Comment: So, this is unpleasant result but this is result. And your tables are in oracle, linked to Sql server. And your oracle runs where, on Unix or Windows? (it is much slower on windows) . Your option is to research. Google : "performance of linked tables from oracle to sql server" , like this one. http://thomaslarock.com/2013/05/top-3-performance-killers-for-linked-server-queries/ I simply think that this is more than just query restructuring

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're running all Windows servers, but I'll have to ask to be totally sure. I will read up on the mentioned subject. Thank you very much for your assistance. Sorry If I was frustrating.

Comment: No issues. Just understand this - your problem is complex one. May be, this is just network. But most likely, this is combination few facts [I bet ya this is #1 issue] that link tables lose all the relationship and indexing, so you running your DB to the ground trying to compile that join with full table searches. Then, Oracle on Windows - here could be another nest of issues http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_builder_linux_oracle.htm You need some serious optimization of your whole setup. This is not a "query" issue that you have

Comment: Update above. Looks like we've got it pretty well managed now. OpenQuery seems to do the trick and let us create a view we can use to link in with local tables and keep things running smoothly. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You should post resolution as answer. There ya go. Open query! so instead on table links - direct access. Cool to know. I was about to suggest, "How long that query runs on oracle itself?"

Comment: *"Okay, I sat down with a guy who knows the Oracle side of this equation better and we came up with the below. Runtime went from over 7 hours to under ten minutes."* - your optimization is **done on Sql server**, not oracle

Comment: Yeah, the optimization was done in sql server manager using OpenQuery() to push the oracle work off onto the oracle server. At least, that's how I understand OpenQuery() to function anyway. It still takes about ten minutes to run, but that's way better than 8 hours and we can now setup SSIS to run it nightly and populate a table in our sql space to increase performance.

Comment: 10 minutes is not a lot for query that has millions of records. And remember that results of it still have to go over to sql server. And it also includes inserts, I understand. your process can always disable indexes for faster inserts and then rebuild them for efficient search later. This is something you should do anyways for the table that gets many inserts

Answer (score 1):

Running this as an OpenQuery seems to have fixed the issue, reducing run time from 7+ hours to under 10 minutes.

Thank you to everyone who looked at it and offered thoughts/assistance.

Working/final code below. :)

```
select asdf.*
from

openquery([TTS], '

Select
INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID,
WS.DATE_ENTERED,
WS.DATE_EXITED,
WFS.DESCRIPTION

From

BT51.INVOICE INV
inner join BT51.WRK on INV.INVOICE_SEQ_ID=WRK.FK_ID
inner join BT51.WRK_STATE WS on WRK.WRK_ID=WS.WRK_ID and WS.DATE_EXITED is null
inner join BT51.WF_STATE WFS on WS.WF_STATE_ID=WFS.WF_STATE_ID


') asdf

inner join occ.amo_occ_stg stg on stg.invoice_seq_id=asdf.INVOICE_SEQ_ID
```